# vim sparkup item number in content

Tags: vim, sparkup

Using the sparkup plugin for vim (specifically vim-gnome on Ubuntu 15.04, although I doubt that matters), I am generating a list with item numbers:

`ion-content.has-tabs > .list > a.item[href=#/item/$]{Item $}*3`

The result substitutes the item number in `[href=#/item/$]` but not in `{Item $}`:

`<ion-content class="has-tabs">
  <div class="list">
    <a href="#/item/1" class="item">Item $</a>
    <a href="#/item/2" class="item">Item $</a>
    <a href="#/item/3" class="item">Item $</a>
  </div>
</ion-content>`

Feature, bug, or user error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am afriad that this plugin deems the `$` in curly braces as a text which should not be affected. To numerate your Item $ list, you can try this command

```
:let @a=1 | %s/\$/\=(@a+setreg('a',@a+1))/g
```

or for selected block in visual mode

```
:let @a=1 | '<,'>s/\$/\=(@a+setreg('a',@a+1))/g
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't remember Sparkup ever supporting incrementing numbers inside "content" braces so I would say "feature".

Don't waste your time asking for a fix on the plugin's issue tracker, though.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Up-voting you for answering the question as I literally asked it, but I accepted the other answer because it provided a workaround as well.

Answer (score 0):

I accepted an answer to the question as I asked it, but I'm adding this to show an alternate approach for a slightly different requirement. I needed to add a nested tag along with the text, which Sparkup does not support. So I found a single 2-step solution to this that also solved the original item number problem (more complex in my real world solution but simplified here).

This sparkup:

`ion-content > .list > a.item.item-icon-left.Item$[href=#/items/$]*3 > i.icon.ion-email`

generates this:

`<ion-content>
  <div class="list">
    <a href="#/items/1" class="item item-icon-left Item1">
      <i class="icon ion-email"></i>
    </a>
    <a href="#/items/2" class="item item-icon-left Item2">
      <i class="icon ion-email"></i>
    </a>
    <a href="#/items/3" class="item item-icon-left Item3">
      <i class="icon ion-email"></i>
    </a>
  </div>
</ion-content>`

Then after I select the lines in visual mode, running this:

`:'<,'>s/ Item\([0-9]*\)">/">Item \1/g`

produces my desired result:

`<ion-content>
  <div class="list">
    <a href="#/items/1" class="item item-icon-left">Item 1
      <i class="icon ion-email"></i>
    </a>
    <a href="#/items/2" class="item item-icon-left">Item 2
      <i class="icon ion-email"></i>
    </a>
    <a href="#/items/3" class="item item-icon-left">Item 3
      <i class="icon ion-email"></i>
    </a>
  </div>
</ion-content>`